# Storefront login page redirects to path with null value instead of j_spring_security_check

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, storefront

We're doing a migration to Hybris 6.5, and while trying to login in the storefront, we are redirected to the path `https://urreab2b.local:9002/urreab2bstorefront/urreab2b/es/USD/null` instead of `https://urreab2b.local:9002/urreab2bstorefront/urreab2b/es/USD/j_spring_security_check`.

Due to this we get a error message `[hybrisHTTP3] [PageNotFound] Request method 'POST' not supported`, which makes sense since the login page in the storefront isn't mapped to null.

We checked in `login.jsp` and the value for `loginActionUrl` is set like this:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sptemplate" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/addons/secureportaladdon/desktop/sptemplate" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spuser" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/addons/secureportaladdon/desktop/spuser" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="cms" uri="http://hybris.com/tld/cmstags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="common" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common" %>


<sptemplate:page pageTitle="${pageTitle}">

    <div id="globalMessages">
        <common:globalMessages/>
    </div>
    <div class="span-24 last login_container">
        <div class="span-9 last login-panel">
            <c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="loginActionUrl"/>
            <spuser:login actionNameKey="login.login" action="${loginActionUrl}"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</sptemplate:page>
```

But whenever we open the login page in the storefront the action value for the login form is set to null:

[image]

We don't understand why the value for the login action url is being overwritten nor who is responsible for this, we've even tried to modify directly the action inside login.tag to `/j_spring_security_check` but even modifying the tag directly doesn't stop the action from being set to null.

Another thing we tried was to modify the action value using Chrome Developer Console, and although we are redirected to the URL `https://urreab2b.local:9002/urreab2bstorefront/urreab2b/es/USD/j_spring_security_check`, and only then we are redirected correctly.

We printed on the JSP the value for action and the value it has is `/urreab2bstorefront/urreab2b/es/USD/j_spring_security_check`, so the value is arriving to the JSP correctly but the form is not taking it.

### EDIT

I found a library called spring-security-taglibs-3.1.1.RELEASE in the lib folder, I removed it so it would take the latest version from the pom.xml, got JasperException due to a tag library using deprecated attribute ifAnyGranted so I replaced them with the recommended, that got rid of the exception but the form is still being assigned null on its action attribute.

Does anyone know what might be the cause? Is it something Spring related or something related to Hybris configuration or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is something related to spring security issue I guess. Could you please the security xml configuration

Comment: Please add this as a comment not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `secureportaladdon` but its not correctly installed to your storefront. Do verify first whether your addon is correctly installed or not. Addon should override the login functionality.

The html code what you are showing seems not to be coming from `secureportaladdon` rather from somewhere else.

Check addon installation step here 
https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8adf7365866910149ceb975f778d809d.html

OR

https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8aeddd34866910149de2d448ff18df98.html

Comment: Indeed we are trying to use secureportaladdon, we tried to uninstall it but it still loaded the action with null, the login page that is loading is the one found in the storefront. As far as I understand uninstalling the addon should fix the null action, isn't it? Or are there more steps to take into consideration?

Comment: One thing to note is that even following the guide to install the `secureportaladdon` the stofront doesn't redirect to the login page from the addon.